# What is the difference between archas, exousias, kosmokratoras? (Ephesians 6:12)

Tags: greek, ephesians

I notice that there are overlapping usages in the different words used here:

Ephesians 6:12 NKJV

12 For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against **principalities**, against **powers**, against the **rulers** of the darkness of this age, against spiritual hosts of wickedness in the heavenly places.

Ephesians 6:12 NIV

12 For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the **rulers**, against the **authorities**, against the **powers** of this dark world and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms.

Ephesians 6:12 NASB

12 For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the **rulers**, against the **powers**, against the **world forces** of this darkness, against the spiritual forces of wickedness in the heavenly places.

[image]

**What are the difference of the three words used here and what is the author trying to say differently by using each of the terms?**

Answer (score 1):

I will not provide a comprehensive explanation of the these three words in Eph 6:12 - such can be found in any good lexicon.  Instead, I will provide a brief explanation of each to show their distinction from each other:

**ἀρχή (arché)**

[In English we get several words from this such as Archon, archaic, etc.  The Latin equivalent word in principia from which English derives words like prince, principality, principal, etc.]

The essential meaning of this word is of one who is capable of initiating something as a ruler, hence the translations like, "Archons", "princes", "rulers", etc.

**ἐξουσία (exousia)**

This word simply means "authority"; when applied to a ruling person (as in Eph 6:12) it means one who has authority to say or do something as a ruler.  Hence the obvious translation, "authorities".

**κοσμοκράτωρ (kosmokratór)**

This compound word consists of two parts:

- kosmos = world
- κράτωρ = strong/mighty ruler

Thus, the obvious meaning is "mighty world rulers".

Now, having said all this, I do not think Paul's use of these three specific words should be obsessed over - it is simply a list of the various names of various types of rulers that are found in any functioning government; in this case the spiritual government of demons "*of this dark world and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms*".

That is, Paul is stating that there exists an unseen world of spiritual demons all of whose leaders/rulers are bent on opposing God and His people, Christians.  What **follows** is far more important to the Christian:

> Eph 6:13-17 - Therefore take up the full armor of God, so that when
> the day of evil comes, you will be able to stand your ground, and
> having done everything, to stand. Stand firm then, with the belt of
> truth buckled around your waist, with the breastplate of righteousness
> arrayed, and with your feet fitted with the readiness of the gospel of
> peace. In addition to all this, take up the shield of faith, with
> which you can extinguish all the flaming arrows of the evil one. And
> take the helmet of salvation and the sword of the Spirit, which is the
> word of God.

Comment: +1. So perhaps it's meant to collectively emphasize the statement rather than state differences between them. Thanks for the answer!